# Automation job with jenkins is fetching tests from cache but not actually executing them. How to actually execute tests?

Tags: selenium, maven, jenkins, automation, jenkins-pipeline

We have automation tests that run on jenkins slave, however some times job get's finished successfully showing 100% tests passed but what is happening actually is, these tests are being fetched from cache and not actually getting executed. We don't want this to happen as it is not reliable to depend on some old cache results. Suggest ways to avoid this, thank you.

I have nothing but to disable and enable job, re executing the job but of no use.

Answer (score 0):

Quite strange, the jenkins in each execution runs a new suite, you can check the slave machine and then the browser by clearing the cache. Look closely at the build executions is the number #

check browser
clear cache
clean project on each run
check slave machine